# Раздельно или слитно: Перечень (не)составленных актов

Tags: орфография, частица-не, слитно-раздельно

Как пишется "Перечень (не)составленных актов"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Противопоставления нет,зависимых слов нет, отрицательных слов нет - следовательно, слитно